# bootstrap 5, label with indicator

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to develop this king of label with top indicator,

[image: label with price]

I think to approach it with:

```
<div class="col-12">
<div class="col-3 bg-dark"> x4 </div>
<div class="col-9 bg-white"> 75€ </div>
</div>
```

but how can I put the triangle / indicator up this div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
  .arrow {
    position:absolute;
    top: -26px;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .arrow::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid black;
  }
  
  .black-bg {
    background-color:#000;
    color: #fff;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div class="black-bg">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

**You can create an arrow like this, please don't mind the height and width of the 'black-bg' and you can change class also you can add bootstrap 5 class to this**

Comment: welcome!_______